# Regex pattern ($) for end of the line is not working properly as its not printing correct output

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

```
import re

with open('testt.txt') as infile:
 for line in infile:
     if 'SF:' in line:
        line2=re.findall('SF:[\/\w]+.c$',line)
        print(line2)
```

i'm getting output

```
['SF:/x/eng/rlse/DOT/devN_170820_0500/zephyr/src/libzapid/https_util.c']
['SF:/x/eng/rlse/DOT/devN_170820_0500/zephyr/src/libzapid/zapid.c']
['SF:/x/eng/rlse/capability_update_registration.c']
```

but i need only below output ,as the last printed output is actually ends with capability_update_registration.cc but its printing that line as registration.c

```
['SF:/x/eng/rlse/DOT/devN_170820_0500/zephyr/src/libzapid/https_util.c']
['SF:/x/eng/rlse/DOT/devN_170820_0500/zephyr/src/libzapid/zapid.c']
```

As this line contains .cc it should not print

```
['SF:/x/eng/rlse/capability_update_registration.cc']
```

Answer (score 0):

The point matches any character. You need to escape it with a blackslash, and you should use the r modifier to keep single backslashes as backslashes in strings:

```
line2=re.findall(r'SF:[/\w]+\.c$',line)
```

Comment: line2=re.findall(r'SF:[\/\w]+\.c',line) $ is not working

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to remove the backslash which escapes the slash.